# How to pass props in react router

Tags: reactjs

I have an App, a Navbar and a Content class, I am trying to pass a prop from navbar to content that will be rendered when I redirect to the content page.

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Home/Navbar';
import Content from './components/Home/Content';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
      return (
        <Router>
            <div>
              <Navbar />
              <Route path="/content" component={Content} render={(props) => <Navbar {...props} test={this.state.test} />} />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

### Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            test: 'test',
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                This is my navbar
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

### Content.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Content extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            x: 'x',
            test: this.props.test
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <p>{this.state.x}</p>
                <p>{this.state.test}</p>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```

The problem that I am having is that is when I redirect to the content page, the state from the navbar class is not being passed through to it. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to have a local state when you could use props instead? Maybe you want to use the `static getInitialStateFromProps`?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how props work to be honest... I just want to pass a read only value from the navbar to the content page so that when I'm on the home page it displays 'This is my navbar' and when I'm on the content page it will display 'This is my navbar' and 'test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem mostly lays in the fact that you are using both `component` and `render` props in your `Route`, you should use only one. If you do not want to change or pass along anything from where your `Route` is defined, you should use `component` property.

If you do wish to pass along some information at that point, use the `render` prop as you have done (however, I believe you really wanted to render the `Content` component and not the `NavBar` as in your OP)

```
<Route path="/content" render={(props) => <Content {...props} test={this.state.test} />} />
```

Then you really don't need any of your local state you were displaying, and content could be a functional component instead, like

```
const Content = ({ x, test }) => (
  <>
    <p>{ x }</p>
    <p>{ test }</p>
  </>);
```

where `x` and `test` would be destructured from your props, giving you easy access to it (you could also use `(props)` and then `props.test` and `props.x` depending on how you like to write it)

Answer (score 0):

u can pass state like this with redirect :

```
<Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/content',
            state: { test: '123' }
        }}
/>
```

and for accessing it :

```
this.props.location.state.test
```